# How to prevent duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how I can have it loop through the data in the UL (each `li`) and prevent it from duplicating any prior existence of a selection.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
// Long version
function HandlerCharacters() {
 var characterid = $('#charactersdrop option:selected').val();
 var characterName = $('#charactersdrop option:selected').text();

 if( characterid > 0 ) {
  // Create the anchor element
  var anchor = $( '<a href="#">Remove</a>' );  

  // Create a click handler for the anchor element
  anchor.click( function() {
   $( this ).parent().remove();
   return false;  // makes the href in the anchor tag ignored
  } );

  // Create the <li> element with its text, and then append the anchor inside it.
  var li = $( '<li>' + characterName + '&nbsp;</li>' ).append( anchor );
  li.data( 'characterid', characterid );

  // Append the new <li> element to the <ul> element
  $( '#characterlist' ).append( li );
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's good. Is there a question?

Comment: Why are you creating the same jQuery object twice?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you're trying to insert a new `li` only when the new `characterID` is not within the data of another `li` in the list. If so, then you could write a function like this:

```
function isDupe(which) {
  var result = false;
  $('ul#the_list li').each( function(i,e) { // look at all list elements
    if ( $(e).data('characterid') == which ) { // compare to argument
      result = true; // matched!
      return false; // break out of .each()
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Then you could wrap your `li` creation code like this:

```
if( !isDupe(characterid) ){
  // do your checks
  // make your li
  // append to your list
}
```

Here's a reduced example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/B7myn/

Comment: There's nothing else that I can add to my existing function to have it loop through do do a check?

Comment: As I mentioned in the bottom part of the answer, just define the function above (you can define it within your function if you wish), and then wrap the guts of your LI-creating pieces in the conditional statement. You could simply change `if( characterid > 0 )` to ` if( characterid > 0 && !isDupe(characterid) )`, for example. I don't know what the rest of your page and code looks like, but here's the kind of thing I mean (possibly non-working, just modifying your code): http://jsfiddle.net/KMK4z/

Comment: Just so I can learn and understand a part of it. What do the "e" and "i" values stand for?

Comment: The function takes two arguments: the `index` and the `element`. I just use "i,e" for brevity. For every iteration through `each()`, `e` is the current element (so, in this case, one of the `<li>` s), and `i` is the index of the current trip through the loop (starting at zero).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for taking a second to explain it me. I've been doing some research about how to pass the end result of the li.data as a parameter to my data string for form processing but I can not find anything that helps me. However another thing that is bothering me is when i do that I need to point out the first value in the li data because I'll be doing something special with that value in my process database file so I'm not sure at one point to point that value out or if I can leave it all fine until it gets to the process page.  http://pastebin.com/nnjS9SMz

Comment: I think you're getting beyond the scope of this particular question; I'd suggest posting another.